# New-ADUser OtherAttributes var from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, var

I'm using the powershell script below to create new AD accounts from a CSV file. I recently added the vars for $extensionAttribute1 and $extensionAttribute2. I also added the following -OtherAttributes = @{'extensionAttribute1' = $extensionAttribute1;'extensionAttribute2'= $extensionAttribute2}

How can I correct for the following error?

New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OtherAttributes'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. At D:\OneDrive\Element Care\Powershell\SACRequest - Create Accounts via CSV.ps1:62 char:30 + ... -OtherAttributes @{'extensionAttribute1' = $extensionAttribute1}

ps script is as follows:

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv "\\server\path\file.csv"

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $Firstname  = $User.'First Name:'
    $Lastname   = $User.'Last Name:'
    $OU         = 'OU=CONTRACTORS,OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=organization,DC=domain,DC=lan'
    $Descritpion = $User.'Account Type'
    $company    = $User.'Employer:'
    $extensionAttribute1 = $User."Submitter Name" # The employee who originally submitted the request.
    $extensionAttribute2 = $User."Submitter email" # The email for who originally submitted the request.

   # $email      = $User.email
   # $streetaddress = $User.streetaddress
   # $city       = $User.city
   # $zipcode    = $User.zipcode
   # $state      = $User.state
   # $country    = $User.country
   # $telephone  = $User.telephone
   # $jobtitle   = $User.jobtitle
   # $department = $User.department

    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@domain.com" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Path $OU `
            -City $city `
            -Company $company `
            -State $state `
            -StreetAddress $streetaddress `
            -OfficePhone $telephone `
            -EmailAddress $email `
            -Title $jobtitle `
            -Department $department `
            -Description $Descritpion `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
            -OtherAttributes @{'extensionAttribute1' = $extensionAttribute1;'extensionAttribute2'= $extensionAttribute2}
    }
    }
```

Comment: In the error message, it looks like the squiggly line is underlining the `=` symbol, which would be invalid. But the code you posted does not have that `=` character present. Maybe you fixed it already? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Clearly this has something to do with spaces in the CSV values. extensionAttribute1  was to be a first and last name. I'll just use extensionAttribute1 and 2 for first and last and use extensionAttribute3 for the email address.

Comment: I would update the original post to include your current error.

Comment: I also see you have fields that end with a colon like `First Name:` and `Employer:`. Are these really the headers in your CSV? Plus, there are typos: `extensionAttrbute1` and `extensionAttrbute2` are both missing the `i`

Comment: Thanks, @NathanW The original is updated now.

Comment: @Theo, yes. The headers ultimately come from a web form. I'm pulling the headers and values from a sql database. Typos are a byproduct of spending too much time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you recieved came IMO from the typo's you have made in the original code.  Apart from that, I would advice you to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for cmdlets like `New-ADUser` that can have a lot of parameters. That way you keep the code both readable and maintainable, and you don't need to use the easily overlooked backtick character for line continuation.

Provided your CSV contains all of the values and all column headers are as shown in your code, something like this should work:

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
Import-csv "\\server\path\file.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if ((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.username)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $($_.username) already exist in Active Directory."
         continue
    }
    # only store these in variables as they are used in multiple properties
    $firstName = $_.'First Name:'
    $lastName  = $_.'Last Name:'
    # create a Hashtable with all properties you want to set for the new user
    $properties = @{
        'SamAccountName'        = $_.username
        'UserPrincipalName'     = '{0}@domain.com' -f $_.username
        'Name'                  = '{0} {1}' -f $firstName, $lastName
        'GivenName'             = $firstName
        'Surname'               = $lastName
        'Enabled'               = $true
        'DisplayName'           = '{0}, {1}' -f $lastName, $firstName
        'Path'                  = 'OU=CONTRACTORS,OU=ACCOUNTS,OU=organization,DC=domain,DC=lan'
        'City'                  = $_.city
        'Company'               = $_.'Employer:'
        'State'                 = $_.state
        'StreetAddress'         = $_.streetaddress
        'OfficePhone'           = $_.telephone
        'EmailAddress'          = $_.email
        'Title'                 = $_.jobtitle
        'Department'            = $_.department
        'Description'           = $_.'Account Type'
        'AccountPassword'       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force) 
        'ChangePasswordAtLogon' = $true
        'OtherAttributes'       = @{'extensionAttribute1' = $_.'Submitter Name';'extensionAttribute2'= $_.'Submitter email'}
        # you can comment out any properties you do not need or are missing in the CSV
        # 'PostalCode'          = $_.zipcode
        # 'Country'             = $_.country
    }
    # create the new user using the properties Hashtable (splat)
    Write-Host "Creating user $($_.username)"
    New-ADUser @properties
}
```

Comment: Splatting looks great but I'm not quite tracking how the _if_ condition works. Is continue working like else?
Your last properly creates the account but I'm getting the error below. --- 
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'xxray' under: 'DC=domain,DC=lan'.
At line:7 char:9
+     if (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.username) {  # SACRequestCSV has the  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xxray:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException

Comment: @nominus Sorry, did the if wrong. Should be fixed now. The `continue` makes the code jump to the top of the loop and perform the next iteration. It skips the code below for that user. It is explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-looping-the-continue-statement/)

Comment: Hi @theo thanks for the update. Using yours and the Dr Scripo example I'm trying to troubleshoot the sequence. The warning triggers properly but it still fires off the New-ADUser. I see that _continue_ should bring us back to the top of the _if_ statement instead of proceeding through, but its executing the rest of the code. How to correct for this?

Comment: More tinkering. If an account already exists the accounts after it are not processed. If an account does not exist, ps errors with Cannot find an object with identity: 'xyz' under: 'DC=domain,DC=lan'. At line:7 char:9  but then proceeds to create the account.

Comment: @nominus Ah, apparently, using the `-Identity` parameter on `Get-ADUser` throws an exception if not found regardless of the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. I've changed the test to use the `-Filter` parameter instead to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is working perfectly now.